# Cisco RVS4000: multi-WAN support?

Tags: cisco

Can anyone confirm if the RVS4000 has multi-WAN and policy routing support?  Manual doesn't really say yes or no, I'm thinking no, knowing Cisco but want to confirm before I recommend another firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heard from the guy on-site that it doesn't do mult-WAN and certainly not policy routing so I'm going to have to accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This actually was a Linksys Small Business product previously.  We were able to set it up for WAN failover between two connections (tricky, because as you say, the manual isn't exactly helpful) but I don't recall it having policy based routing.

More than happy to be proven wrong though!

Comment: do you recall being able to specify which gateway to use on firewall rules?

Comment: There may well have been that option, yes.  Using the firewall to that spec was a little outside the scope of the task.  The client was after load balancing which didn't seem to be explicitly available, however, routing out VIA the firewall was, I think...